# Как связать изображение (кастомный значок поиска) в CollapsingToolbarLayout и кнопку поиска из меню?

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, в приложении стоит `collapsingtoolbarlayout` со скрытой строкой меню, а на выезжающем toolbar'е имеется небольшой кастомный значок поиска, заменяющий собой кнопку поиска в меню. Не могу понять как в обработчике событий `onClick` этого значка задать задачу, чтобы он использовал непосредственно кнопку поиска из меню.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById((R.id.collapsing_toolbar));
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    mLupa = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menulupa);
    mLupa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    ...

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action1_search:

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchResultsActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
                return true;
            case R.id.testDataPush:
                new TestPush(this, Utils.GetPushToken(this), "пуш типа data", "data").execute();
                return true;
            case R.id.testNotificationPush:
                new TestPush(this, Utils.GetPushToken(this), "пуш типа notification", "notification").execute();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Заранее извиняюсь, если вопрос некорректный, я только разбираюсь в разработке на android[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы назначили `Toolbar` исполнять функции `ActionBar` (`setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);`). Теперь вам не надо помещать в тулбар иконки через разметку и как то связывать эти иконки с иконками меню, создавайте меню, как для экшенбара (через [переопределение методов OptionsMenu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html?hl=ru#options-menu)) и они отобразятся в тулбаре, при этом никакую разметку к тулбару назначать не нужно.

Для того, чтобы скрыть `ActionBar`, не надо вызывать у него `hide()` - используйте одну из тем с NoActionBar в имени темы, например тему `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`

**UPDATE** Если вам требуется осуществлять один и тот же поиск при нажатии на разные иконки (одна в `ActionBar`, другая в `Toolbar`), то выделите код, осуществляющий поиск в отдельный метод. При обработке нажатия и на нужный пункт в меню и на иконку в тулбаре, вызывайте этот метод. В вашем случае:

```
....
mLupa = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menulupa);
mLupa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startSearch();
    }
});
...
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action1_search:
            startSearch();
            return true;
  ....
}

private void startSearch(){
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchResultsActivity.class);
      startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
}
```

Comment: Не совсем то, что мне нужно, закрепил скриншот макета, чтобы было понятнее.

Comment: pavlofff, огромное вам спасибо, всё работает! Очень меня выручили.